# 401 Unauthorized error when accessing webapi from angular

Tags: angularjs, iis, asp.net-web-api

I need to capture a user's domain\username when they access my webapi app. On my dev machine I have my webapi at `localhost:10570` and my angularjs website which makes calls to the webservice at `localhost:34575`.

If I make a call directly to my webapi app everything works fine. I can see the users domain and username and the service returns the requested data as JSON. But if I access my angularjs site and angular makes the call to webapi then I get 401 unauthorized for every call against the service.

In my WebApi app's web.config I have:

```
<system.web>
    <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.5.2" />
    <httpRuntime targetFramework="4.5.2" />
    <authentication mode="Windows" />
  </system.web>
  <system.webServer>
    <httpProtocol>
  <customHeaders>
    <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Origin" value="http://localhost:34575" />
    <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Methods" value="POST, PUT, DELETE, GET, OPTIONS" />
    <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Headers" value="content-Type, accept, origin, X-Requested-With, Authorization, name" />
    <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Credentials" value="true" />
  </customHeaders>
</system.webServer>
```

I have this in IIS Express for Visual Studio 2015's applicationhost.config file:

```
<location path="MyNamespace.WebAPI">
    <system.webServer>
        <security>
            <authentication>
                <windowsAuthentication enabled="true" />
                <anonymousAuthentication enabled="false" />
            </authentication>
        </security>
    </system.webServer>
</location>
```

My angularjs site is part of the same solution at "MyNamespace.Client".

Why does accessing the web service directly work fine, but accessing it via the angular app fail?

Comment: You need use Bearer Token. See http://bitoftech.net/2014/06/09/angularjs-token-authentication-using-asp-net-web-api-2-owin-asp-net-identity/, http://www.dotnetcurry.com/aspnet/1223/secure-aspnet-web-api-using-tokens-owin-angularjs and http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/ff2f08/token-based-authentication-using-Asp-Net-web-api-in-angularj/

Comment: @gpaoli Luckily bearer tokens weren't necessary in this instance. Looks like a lot of work.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

I didn't realize you have to tell Angular to send your credentials to the server. I just had to change my API calls from:

```
$http.get(url);
```

to

```
$http.get(url, { withCredentials: true });
```

Comment: hmm that gives me a different error: A wildcard '*' cannot be used in the 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header when the credentials flag is true.
but when i remove it I get: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.

Comment: @SonicSoul That looks like a CORS error. If your angular app is backed by a web service and they're on separate domains or the same domain with different ports you'll have to use CORS. Perhaps it's not configured correctly? If this is .NET, the settings will be in your web.config.

Comment: yep, the wildcard in question is in the web.config. I've gotten to a point where i can get all get's to work but not the put's ..

Comment: @SonicSoul Are you using Chrome? Chrome has issues with CORS and sites hosted on localhost. So if your web service is at `localhost:1234` and your angular site is at `localhost:9876`, anything other than `GET` requests will be problematic. Try in IE and see what happens.

Comment: @SonicSoul If the problem is coming from the web service, usually you'll see an error about preflight options. I found I had to add a public function called `GetOptions` to each of my controllers. I gave it the `[HttpOptions]` attribute and it only has one line in it: `return Ok();`

Comment: I have the same problem !
It works in IE but not chrome. Is the CORS issue in Chrome still not resolved ?