# User validation not working if made in a different browser, "the server responded with a status of 401 (Unauthorized)"

Tags: angular, apache, symfony, security

As most websites, I ask the user to validate his account by sending him an email then redirecting him to my website and modifying the "emailValidation" column in the database.

It works fine only if the user clicks his email from the same browser or navigation session where he registered.
If the user validates his account from his phone, for example, it will be redirected to the login page but his account won't be validated.
Any idea what is wrong?
Thanks for your help

**The confirmation page:**

```
export class ConfirmationPageComponent implements OnInit {
  user: any;
  data: any = [];
  token: string;

  constructor(
    private activatedRoute: ActivatedRoute,
    private router: Router,
    private formBuilder: FormBuilder,
    private authenticationService: AuthenticationService,
    public notificationsService: NotificationsService
  ) {
    this.activatedRoute.params.subscribe((params) => {
      if (params['token']) {
        this.token = params['token'];
      }
    });
  }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.authenticationService.verifyToken(this.token).subscribe(
      (res) => {
        if (this.authenticationService.getToken() !== null) {
          this.router.navigate(['/newArticle']);
          setTimeout(
            function () {
              this.notificationsService.success('', 'Votre compte a été activé avec succès');
            }.bind(this),
            500
          );
        } else {
          this.router.navigate(['/login']);
        }
      },
      (error) => {
        this.router.navigate(['/login']);
      }
    );
  }
```

**The activation function**

```
/**
     * @param UserRepository $userRepository
     * @param $token
     * @return bool|User
     * @Rest\View(serializerGroups={"user"})
     * @Rest\Get("/inscription/verifyToken/{token}", name="contact_check_token_exists")
     */
    public function verifyToken(UserRepository $userRepository, $token)
    {
        $user = $userRepository->findOneBy(["token" => $token]);
        if ($user) {
            $createdAt = $user->getCreatedAt();
            $date = $createdAt->format('Y-m-d H:i:s');
            $tomorrowDate = date('Y-m-d H:i:s', strtotime('+24 hour', strtotime($date)));
            if ($date < $tomorrowDate && $user->getStatus() !== USER::ACTIf) {
                $user->setEmailValidation(true);
                $user->setStatus(User::ACTIf);
                $this->em->flush();
                return true;
            } else {
                return false;
            }
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    }
```

**UPDATE**

The confirmation page directly sends me to the login page with the following errors, which makes me think that the url api.*******/inscription/verifyToken/ is unauthorized.
But if I click on this url, the validation is made.

So what makes this link unauthorized the first time and creates the not found error?

[image]
[image]

Could be come from the apache configuration?

Comment: Seems like the token is no being sent, that's why you get the 401. Check the request on network tab and verify if the token is present

Comment: You are sending users to /login when not authenticated, and validating token from email is always in an unauthenticated state (or at least from other browsers). So you need to confirm email and authenticate a user at the same time.

Comment: @Flash this.authenticationService.verifyToken(this.token) validates the user account then I send him to the login page.

Comment: @Cantinou and you do this by sending request to `/inscription/verifyToken/{token}`? Please check your security configs `access_control` section, your URL should be accessible anonymously (see https://symfony.com/doc/current/security.html#allowing-unsecured-access-i-e-anonymous-users)

Comment: @Flash , it's accessible anonymously. path: ^/api/user/inscription, roles: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY } Which is strange, when the confirmation email is loading, its says "cannot found the url" of the api. But when I click on the url in the error message it can.

Comment: @AmadouBeye, it says "cannot found the url"

Comment: Please provide a your security (firewalls and access control list)

Comment: The error comes from Google Chrome.
I found the answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39170713/401-unauthorized-error-when-accessing-webapi-from-angular

Answer (score -2):

### Problem

You have problem with security layer in Symfony. What you must know before fix: all controllers handled only if user success pass via security level (firewall, access control, grand permissions, etc...).

### In you case (when success scenario):

1. You previously authorize user (token success stored).
2. You redirect user to secured endpoint (by firewall or access control).
3. Symfony check security, and all OK, because system write token in 1 step.
4. All OK, controller handled.

### In you case (when fail scenario):

1. You previously authorize user (token success stored).
2. You redirect user to secured endpoint (by firewall or access control).
3. User open page in new browser (new session for symfony).
4. Symfony check security, but fail because session is empty.
5. Controller not handled and returns 401/403 error.

### Solution

You must check you security configuration, and:

1. Allow anonymous users in you firewall for this endpoint (https://symfony.com/doc/current/security/firewall_restriction.html).
2. Check access control for you route (where you verify token) and allow for IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY (https://symfony.com/doc/current/security.html#allowing-unsecured-access-i-e-anonymous-users).